# How to let jhitranslate translate a tag attribute like title?

Tags: jhipster

**I want to translate the title attribute of a span tag.**

Something like this:

```
<span [title]="jhiTranslate('enroll.title')">Enroll</span>
```

I couldn't find any documentation that explained how to use jhiTranslate:

- How to use their directives
- Or how to call it imperatively

Here is my i18n json:

```
{
 "enroll":{"title":"Enroll this student"}
}
```

Comment: What happens when you do that? Nothing? Wrong value? No translation?

Comment: @Bob Dalgleish Hi, sorry for the ambiguity, I have amend my question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try their translation pipe

```
<span [title]="{{'enroll.title'| translate}}">Enroll</span>
```

Answer (score 4):

The correct syntax for jHipster right now is:

```
<span jhiTranslate="enroll.title">Enroll</span>
```

Comment: @LeszekJasek, yup, my solution is specifically for jHipster but translate pipe also works :)

Answer (score 1):

In JHipster version 6.5.1 (and probably upwards) the translation for attributes does not use the {{ }} anymore.

The working version in is

```
<span [title]="'enroll.title'| translate">Enroll</span>
```